# How to get an exception on inaccurate calculation?

Tags: c#, decimal, precision

Every time we need a high decimal-precision, we use decimals to do the calculations. Is there any way to check if the precision did suffice for the calculation?

I would like to make the following code throw an exception:

```
decimal almostMax = Decimal.MaxValue - 1;
decimal x = almostMax + 0.1m; // This should create an exception, since x equals almostMax.
Assert.AreEqual(x, almostMax); // This does NOT fail.
```

It doesn't really matter in real code, but it would be nice to be safe.

Comment: Decimals have a precision of 28 digits (some, but not all, values can have 29 digits). As Decimal.MaxValue is a 28digit number, adding 0.1m is exceeding the precision of the decimal, which is why the two values are equal & the Assert does not fail.

Comment: @PaulF, I think OP is aware of that. He is looking for a way to detect this problem during runtime.

Comment: Please bear in mind that an exception is a heavyweight operation and should only be used for things that should not happen. If it is likely that some calculations will fail, you should instead use a pattern like "TryParse" which returns boolean instead of throwing and would be much quicker.

Comment: I am not sure the OP does understand that - checking if the value is close to the maximum allowed value is not the same as checking the number is close to it's precision - which could fail close to zero if the value added were 10 to -29 for example. The only way to check if the decimal value has sufficient precision is to check the number of digits the value has - it could be done with this method by examining the required number of digits for the result - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx

Comment: @PaulF I am very sure the OP does understand that :-) I am indeed looking for an easy way to check this automatically during runtime. And I would like to avoid doing it manually (e.g. by implementing a SafeDecimal).

Comment: This would be quite complex - you could be adding two values well within range of the decimal - a 14 digit integer value decimal to a small number with 15 decimal digits and exceed the precision of a decimal. Maybe what you need to do is check if  both values are not zero then you throw an exception if the sum is not equal to both values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension method should help. It reverses the operation and checks if the input arguments can be calculated correctly from the result. If that's not the case then the operation caused precision loss.

```
public static decimal Add(this decimal a, decimal b)
{
    var result = a + b;

    if (result - a != b || result - b != a)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Precision loss!");

    return result;
}
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vx6UYY

If you want to use the regular operators like `+` etc, you have to go with [Philipp Schmid's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952890/1025555) and implement the operators on your own decimal type.

Comment: Careful though, it doesn't check that the result is accurate. When trying to add `11m`, if `10m` gets added instead, this method doesn't throw an exception. `(result - a != b || result - b != a)` should cover that, if I'm not overlooking any special cases.

Comment: That's a nice one that might even keep the performance-impact at a reasonable level.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a SaveDecimal class and overload the + operator 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
public class SafeDecimal
{
    private decimal DecValue;

    public SafeDecimal(decimal Value)
    {
        DecValue = Value;
    }

    public decimal GetValue()
    {
        return DecValue;
    }

    public static SafeDecimal operator +(SafeDecimal A, SafeDecimal B)
    {
        decimal almostMax = Decimal.MaxValue - 1;

        checked
        {
            if (almostMax <= A.GetValue() + B.GetValue())
                throw new Exception("----scary error message----");
        }

        return new SafeDecimal(A.GetValue() + B.GetValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it take into account negative values?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I should probably fix that, thank you.

Comment: C# already offers overflow protection for arithemtic operations (see this example: http://csharppad.com/gist/7f4edd08bde1061201ca13dca9332806). You are re-implementing something that is already there, plus the question was about precision-loss not overflows. The general idea of the solution seems fine though. Just change the code so that `+` throws an exception under the conditions specified by the OP and this answer is good IMO.

Comment: I hope I got it right this time, correct me if not. I couldn't open your link (website blocked), Abbondanza, but googling helped. I didn't know about the ´checked´ keyword myself tbh. I did a short test and it seems to work. The code still doesn't check for very small numbers but I'm a bit in a hurry right now and I might add that later. Will read every comment to improve this code